# integer divided by other integer constant defined by macro returns incorrect in C?

Tags: c

in the following code the output is **30** ! , it should be 0. am I missing something?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define L 30
#define N2 L * L

    int main() {


        unsigned int id = 30;

        printf("k = %d\n", id/N2); //this prints 30 but  30/900 should be zero!
        printf("k = %d\n", id/900); //this prints 0  OK!

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Try manually expanding your macros and see what that looks like

Comment: `#define N2 L * L` should be `#define N2 (L * L)`. Brackets matter.

Comment: what a mistake!

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal : Ideally, the replacement should be `((L) * (L))` so that the expected answer is produce with an argument such as `A + B`.  Without the inner parentheses, you don’t get the expected result if `A` is 20 and `B` is 10.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you are correct, my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order of operations:

`30 / 30 * 30` is `1 * 30`. `30 / 900` is `0`.

You need to parenthesize in your macro to get the right behaviour:

```
#define N2 (L * L)
```

Comment: It really needs parentheses around each `L` in the replacement.

Comment: This is why using `const` is better than `#define` if that's an option. A `#define` gets *expanded* in the code itself. A `const` is evaluated and computed before its introduction.

Comment: @tadman: This has nothing to do with using macros, but simply not using the correct code. And in C, `const` does not mean "constant".

Comment: @toohonestforthissite In C++ "fancy C" mode it can.

Comment: There is no "C mode" in C++ (fancy or not). Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics!

Answer (score 0):

```
#define N2 (L * L)
```

or

```
printf("k = %d\n", id/(N2));
```

would do the trick.

Comment: It really needs parentheses around each `L` in the replacement text.

Comment: It really does. Imagine when someone wants to clarify that L is the sum of two other items.... `#define L 10 + 20`